# How to get input value from user and then sent to 2 different controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a e-commerce website.I want to create 2 button is `add to cart` and `buy now` as the following:
[image]

When I press `add to cart` product then is added to cart with quantity is selected .I used `form` to do that as the following

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("add_to_cart","Home",new {productId=Model.id_xe},FormMethod.Post)){
                    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1"/>

                    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
                }
```

When I submit, action `add_to_cart` is executed and the rest I guarantee is fine

When I press button `Add to cart` ,it just execute action `add_to_cart` in `Home` controller .I want to create `buy now` button get quantity from input that has `name=quantity`above to `Add to cart` first and then show information of that cart

The main purpose I want to question is that is it possible to create `buy now` button that still get value from input tag above `<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1"/>` to 
 `Add to cart` first and then show information of that cart

If you guys have any ways to help me create `buy now` button please show me.

Comment: i think you need to define property in model and use like this `value="@item.Quantity"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to identify which button was pressed to post the form. In the `add_to_cart` action you can check that. Change the buttons to the followings:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("add_to_cart","Home",new {productId=Model.id_xe},FormMethod.Post)){
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"/>
    <button type="submit" name="addToCart" value="btnAdd">Add to cart</button>
    <button type="submit" name="buyNow" value="btnBuy">Buy Now</button>
}
```

Then In the action:

```
public ActionResult add_to_cart(string button)
{
    //Add the item to the cart here//

    if (button == "addToCart"){
        //return ajax or view result as you have now
    }

    if (button == "buyNow"){
        return RedirectToAction(“~/CartControllerName/CartViewActionName”);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The above is assuming your `number` input field is getting populated properly. If not then write the following code to set the value dynamically based on the drop down's selection change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#qtyDDL').on('change', function () {
        var selectedVal = $.trim($("#qtyDDL:selected").text()); 
        $("#quantity").val(selectedVal );
    });
});
```

`qtyDDL` is the assumed ID of the drop down list.

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I mean.I tried to do that a lot of time

Comment: the value of button is passed to `add_to_cart ` action always is null.I have to pass name of button to `add_to_cart` to action like`public ActionResult add_to_cart(string addToCart)` and then check whether addToCart=='btnAdd' or not